# Editing PDF metadata fields with Python3 and pdfrw

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, metadata, pdfrw

I'm trying to edit the metadata `Title` field of PDFs, to include the ASCII equivalents when possible. I'm using Python3 and the module [`pdfrw`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfrw/).

How can I do string operations that replace the metadata fields?

My test code is here:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfString
import unicodedata

def edit_title_metadata(inpdf):

    trailer = PdfReader(inpdf)

    # this statement is breaking pdfrw
    trailer.Info.Title = unicode_normalize(trailer.Info.Title)

    # also have tried:
    #trailer.Info.Title = PdfString(unicode_normalize(trailer.Info.Title))

    PdfWriter("test.pdf", trailer=trailer).write()
    return

def unicode_normalize(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    edit_title_metadata('Anadon-2011-Scientific Opinion on the safety e.pdf')
```

And the traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_metadata.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "get_metadata.py", line 54, in main
    edit_title_metadata(pdf)
  File "get_metadata.py", line 11, in edit_title_metadata
    trailer.Info.Title = PdfString(unicode_normalize(trailer.Info.Title))
  File "get_metadata.py", line 18, in unicode_normalize
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
  File "/path_to_python/python3.7/site-packages/pdfrw/objects/pdfstring.py", line 550, in encode
    if isinstance(source, uni_type):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

---

Notes:

- [This issue](https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor/issues/11) at GitHub may be related.
- FWIW, Also getting same error with Python3.6
- I've shared the pdf (which has non-ascii hyphens, unicode char \u2010)

.

```
 wget https://gist.github.com/philshem/71507d4e8ecfabad252fbdf4d9f8bdd2/raw/cce346ab39dd6ecb3a718ad3f92c9f546761e87b/Anadon-2011-Scientific%2520Opinion%2520on%2520the%2520safety%2520e.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `.decode()` method on the metadata fields:

```
trailer.Info.Title = unicode_normalize(trailer.Info.Title.decode())
```

And full working code:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfReader
import unicodedata

def edit_title_metadata(inpdf):

    trailer = PdfReader(inpdf)
    trailer.Info.Title = unicode_normalize(trailer.Info.Title.decode())
    PdfWriter("test.pdf", trailer=trailer).write()
    return

def unicode_normalize(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    edit_title_metadata('Anadon-2011-Scientific Opinion on the safety e.pdf')
```

Comment: _sometimes writing the question leads to the answer_