# How to set the title of a new tab when returning a fileresponse

Tags: python, django, http, browser

I have an  button that when pressed opens up a new tab and displays a PDF. When the new tab is opened the title looks like some sort of metadata about the PDF. ex: "Microsoft Powerpoint:The original.ppt" instead of the name of the PDF "Generated.pdf". How do I set the title of the tab to be the name of the actual PDF being displayed?

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('{% url 'get_file' %}','_blank');" value="Show File"/></td>
```

views.py:

```
 def GetFile(request)
    filepath = os.path.join('my_path/' + variable + '/' + filename)
    response = FileResponse(open(filepath, 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="{}"'.format(filename)
    return response
```

Comment: The browser is displaying a piece of metadata from the PDF file. You need a PDF-specific library to modify the PDF so it has the title you want. Here's an example with pdfrw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233416/editing-pdf-metadata-fields-with-python3-and-pdfrw

Answer (score 0):

Think this is missing the disposition!

Try

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
```

or

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
```

`attachment;` should result in a browser window asking what you want to do with the file. "Save as" will be one option. `inline;` should invoke the relevant application on the client machine with no further prompt. Details are browser-specific, though.

Comment: attachment; results in the file downloading (with the correct filename) inline; the file opens in a new tab (which is desired) but filename(in the tab header) is still incorrect

Comment: I don't know whether  you can control browser behaviour  for inline. Have you investigated multiple browsers Chrome, Firefox, Edge? Here's the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266

Comment: Maybe re-ask as a question tagged about browsers in general or browser-of-choice? (Don't know if those tags exist). Also tag HTTP?

Comment: Its the same behavior in different browsers. I think I do need to edit the metadata:title of the PDF before sending it to the browser....